# Node Js value not showing in notification when testing

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am making a notification using firebase cloud functions with node js and my app made on swift

this is my payload

```
  var payload = {
       notification: {
         title: (goOfflineTimePeriod,"Inactive for minutes you are now offline"),
         body: "Time period for inactive log off can be changed in your settings"
```

though my notification my notification only shows as; "Inactive for minutes you are now offline", "Time period for inactive log off can be changed in your settings"

so the variable; goOfflineTimePeriod does not show in the notification

I am only new to node js is there a reason why "goOfflineTimePeriod" does not show in the notification?

here is my full node js function code;

```
exports.goOfflineAlert = functions.firestore
.document('/goneOffline/{uid}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {

  var db = admin.firestore();
  var uid = context.params.uid;
  const newValue = snap.data();
  const goOfflineTimePeriod = newValue.goneOffline;

console.log('uid is',uid)

  var cityRef = db.collection('Users').doc(uid);
 var getDoc = cityRef.get()
     .then(doc => {
       if (!doc.exists) {
         return console.log('No such document!');
       } else {

          const newValue = doc.data();
          const age = newValue.Age;
          const name = newValue['Display Name'];
          const fcmToken = newValue.fcmToken;
          const goOfflineTimePeriod = newValue.goOfflineTimePeriod;


     console.log('Document data:', doc.data(),age,fcmToken,name,goOfflineTimePeriod);

     var payload = {
       notification: {
         title: (goOfflineTimePeriod,"Inactive for minutes you are now offline"),
         body: "Time period for inactive log off can be changed in your settings"



       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`,` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comma) does not concatenate strings in JavaScript, but it returns the second operand. Instead you should use `+` or template string. For example:

```
title: goOfflineTimePeriod+" Inactive for minutes you are now offline",
```